# Virtual host on Apache 2 isn't working as excpected

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to set a development server on my OSX 10.8.2. The deployed site name is `mattat.org.il` so I'd like to set it to `mattat.dev`.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Uncommented the include for virtual hosts, in `httpd.conf`:

   `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. added a virtual host to `httpd-hosts.conf`:

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/matanya/Sites/matat"
   ServerName mattat.dev
   </VirtualHost>`
   ```
3. Added the server name to `etc/hosts`:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
   ::1             localhost.
   fe80::1%lo0 localhost
   127.0.0.1 mattat.dev
   ```
4. Restarted Apache.

Now, when i go to `localhost` it takes me to the directory I've set for the virtual host, instead of taking me the the root directory (i.e `Sites`).
When I go to `mattat.dev` it is unidentified as a valid url, and simply interpreted as a Google search.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `http://mattat.dev` since .dev is not a valid TLD, your browser is not treating it as a URL.  Also check that you still have a  default configuration in your `httpd.conf`, otherwise Apache will result to the virtual host, regardless of what server name it is passed.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed works. But why does `localhost` also send me there?

Comment: ok, got it. I've explicitly added `localhost` to my virtual hosts and now it works. Also, instead of `http://` it is possible to add a forward slash at the end, for the browser to identify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.dev is not a valid TLD, your browser is not treating it as a URL. `http://mattat.dev` should work.

For not recognising localhost, check that you have a default directory in your httpd.conf for Apache to fall back on if it cannot find a virtual host, or alternatively add a second Virtual host for localhost.

```
<Directory "/Users/matanya/Sites/">
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```